# Simplifying node request code for calling refresh token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Suppose that I have a scenario below when doing a http request via node request module.
1) For every API call, if access token is valid, return the response.
2) If Access token is not valid, call refresh token to get new access token. If new access token is being return, call back the same api again, else redirect user to login page.

I have code as below but I feel like it is too redundant to repeat the same steps for each and every api. Is there any way to simplify the process? I am expecting something like this as the end result:

Final expectation code:

```
    var callApiA = {
        ..
        ..
        shouldCallRefreshToken: true
    }
    request(callApiA, function(err, response, body) {
        if(response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.json(body);
        }
    });
```

Current Code:

```
request(callApiA, function(err, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        res.json(body);
    } else if (body.invalidToken) {
        if (refresh token still exist) {
            request(callRefreshToken, function(err, response, body) {
                if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                   request(callApiA, function(err, response, body) {
                        if(body.invalidToken) {
                            res.redirect('/login');
                        } else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                            res.json(body);
                        } else {
                            res.json('unknown error');
                        }
                   });
                } else {
                   res.redirect('/');
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    } else {
        response.json('Unknown error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Bit of a side note...if you want to simplify node async requests, look into using promises, you can still use request if you like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be a bit cleaner.

```
function reqApis(call, callback){
    request(call, callback);
}
function reqTokenCallback( err, response, body) {
   if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      reqApis(callApiA, reqApiCallback);
   } else {
      res.redirect('/');
   }
}
function reqApiCallback( err, response, body ) {
   if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        res.json(body);
    } else if (body.invalidToken) {
        if (refresh token still exist) {
            reqApis(callRefreshToken, reqTokenCallback);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    } else {
        response.json('Unknown error');
    }
}

reqApis(callApiA, reqApiCallback);
```